# Appending a new row to DataFrame depending on a condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to populate a new dataframe with the rows from an existing one if a certain string is found in one of the columns of the existing one.

`topics_data` is a DataFrame of 100 rows with columns 'title','score','url','created'. I'm basically just searching whether the ticker is in the title.

```
tickers = ['AAPL', 'GOOG']
publications = pd.DataFrame(columns=['ticker','title','score','url','created'])
for ticker in tickers:
    for i in range(0,len(topics_data['title'])):
        if ticker.lower() in topics_data['title'][i].lower():
            publications.append({'ticker':ticker,'title':topics_data['title'][i],'score':topics_data['score'][i],
                            'url':topics_data['url'][i],'created':topics_data['created'][i]},ignore_index=True)
```

When I print the content of `publications` it's empty.

Comment: `publications.loc[publications['ticker'].isin(tickers)]` ?

Comment: Chris's vectorized answer is a much better approach than a nested for loop

Comment: Regarding your existing code, it seems like you renamed some of the dfs in one place but not another. What is `topics_data` vs `publications` vs `posts`?

Comment: Noah, you're right. I had renamed one of the dfs in one place but not another. 'topics_data' is the existing database and I'm trying to populate a new one called 'publications' with data from 'topics_data' and the ticker in a separate column.